# How can i send an html and variables together in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, send

I need to send an html and some variables.
I think i can't use locals or res.render since it's not a view, each client can have different pages.
The pages are stored in MongoDB (the html with the variables i need to send),
so when they ask for the html i should send it all together.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should separate the variables from the html. No need to save html in the database.
What you need is a templating engine. If you use express, you can use "Jade" or "Handlebars". I like Handlebars because it looks more like HTML.. https://www.npmjs.org/package/express3-handlebars

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can get the value of the html as a String and then make some regex to change values.
Anyways I think too its better a template engine like Jade.